# How to send a message to a third-party Telegram bot and retrieve the response using PHP?

Tags: php, message, telegram-bot

I've searched both SO and Google and couldn't find what I need. I'm trying to see if it is possible to send a message to a Telegram bot (which I'm not it's owner/writer) and receive the response. The bot that I'm trying to communicate with through my PHP script will get a text message and in return sends back a proper file regarding the initial request. I want my web server be able to send that request and save the returning file in a specific folder on my server.

Is this possible at all?

What I've been seeing all over is sending messages to users as a Telegram bot. In here I want to do it the other way, sending a message to a bot as a user.

Many thanks

Comment: No, bots can not talk to each other. It might be possible to use telegram-cli.

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for a bot. Any solution that works is welcomed. What does telegram-cli actually do?

Comment: telegram-cli acts as a normal user, with a number etc.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I've installed the telegram-cli on the server but don't know how to work with it. Also I couldn't find a geed helping document in that regard. Are you familiar with it?